# Help Needed!! Compiling C++ program - errors

Tags: c++

This is a routine that I believe is for C.  I copied it (legally) out a book and am trying to get it to compile and run in visual studio 2008.  I would like to keep it as a C++ program. Lots of programming experience in IBM mainframe assembler but none in C++.  Your help is greatly appreciated.  I think just a couple of simple changes but I have read tutorials and beat on this for hours - getting nowhere.  Getting a lot (4) of error C2440 '=' : cannot convert form 'void*' to to 'int*' errors in statements past the reedsolomon function:  Thanks so much! Program follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int wd[50] = {131,153,175,231,5,184,89,239,149,29,181,153,175,191,153,175,191,159,231,3,127,44,12,164,59,209,104,254,150,45};
int nd = 30, nc=20, i, j, k, *log, *alog, *c, gf=256, pp=301;  

/* The following is routine which calculates the error correction codewords
for a given data codeword string of length "nd", stored as an integer array wd[].
The function ReedSolomon()first generates log and antilog tables for the Galois
Field of size "gf" (in the case of ECC 200, 28) with prime modulus "pp"
(in the case of ECC 200, 301), then uses them in the function prod(), first to
calculate coefficients of the generator polynomial of order "nc" and then to
calculate "nc" additional check codewords which are appended to the data in wd[].*/

/* "prod(x,y,log,alog,gf)" returns the product "x" times "y" */

int prod(int x, int y, int *log, int *alog, int gf)
    {if (!x || !y) 
        return 0;
    else
        return alog[(log[x] + log[y]) % (gf-1)];
    }
/* "ReedSolomon(wd,nd,nc,gf.pp)" takes "nd" data codeword values in wd[] */
/* and adds on "nc" check codewords, all within GF(gf) where "gf" is a */
/* power of 2 and "pp" is the value of its prime modulus polynomial */

void ReedSolomon(int *wd, int nd, int nc, int gf, int pp) 
{int i, j, k, *log,*alog,*c;

/* allocate, then generate the log & antilog arrays: */
   log = malloc(sizeof(int) * gf);
   alog = malloc(sizeof(int) * gf);
   log[0] = 1-gf; alog[0] = 1;
   for (i = 1; i < gf; i++)
       {alog[i] = alog[i-1] * 2;
       if (alog[i] >= gf) alog[i] ^= pp;
          log[alog[i]] = i;
       }
/* allocate, then generate the generator polynomial coefficients: */
   c = malloc(sizeof(int) * (nc+1));
   for (i=1; i<=nc; i++) c[i] = 0; c[0] = 1;
   for (i=1; i<=nc; i++)
       {c[i] = c[i-1];
        for (j=i-1; j>=1; j--)
        {c[j] = c[j-1] ^ prod(c[j],alog[i],log,alog,gf);
        }
        c[0] = prod(c[0],alog[i],log,alog,gf);
       }
/* clear, then generate "nc" checkwords in the array wd[] : */
   for (i=nd; i<=(nd+nc); i++) wd[i] = 0;
   for (i=0; i<nd; i++)
       {k = wd[nd] ^ wd[i] ;
        for (j=0; j<nc; j++)
            {wd[nd+j] = wd[nd+j+1] ^ prod(k,c[nc-j-1],log, alog,gf);
            }
       }
    free(c);
    free(alog);
    free(log);
    return ();
}
int main ()
   {reedsolomon (50,30,20,256,301);
    for (i = 1; i < 51; i++)
    {cout<< i; "="; wd[i];}
    cout<<"HEY, you, I'm alive! Oh, and Hello World!\n";
    cin.get();
    return 1;
   }
```

Comment: This is unreadable. If you want others to read your code, please [pick an indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and use it like everyone else.

Comment: I would send multiple flame emails if a coworker wrote code like this.

Comment: OMG!! It's working. I love it - it's orgasmic!! Thanks to hobbs, Andres. The great helpers! And to you snot baggers meager, 0xc0deface. We can always count on some snotty comments from folks like you the first time we post on a new site with our 1st program in a new language.  FYI meager - the code is indented and looks good - something happened when I hit submit.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, a void pointer can't be implicitly cast to a different pointer.

So instead of

```
int *pInt;
pInt = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

You need to say

```
int *pInt;
pInt = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

or preferably

```
int *pInt = new int[5];
```

(with a matching `delete[]` instead of `free`), or preferably preferably use a `vector` if it's intended to be dynamic.

Comment: use `delete[]` if you use `new T[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the program type: `#include <cstdlib>` . If you do not include this library, then malloc will not work. In C++, void* to int* is not an automatic conversion, in lines: 31 32 and 40 you need to cast to int* e.g: log = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * gf);
At main funcion, line 63 you're calling the function as reedsolomon, it should be ReedSolomon, the way you declared it.

Also, in "void ReedSolomon(int *wd, int nd, int nc, int gf, int pp)" when you call the function in the main, you say ReedSolomon (50,30,20,256,301);  so you are asigning an int value to a pointer to int, that's a type clash. I'm not sure what it is you want to do with wd.

Next time, please post the errors from the compiler so people dont have to compile the code themselves to check and see whats wrong.

Also a good technique which will save you a lot of time is to do a google search on the error the compiler gives you (it is very likely somebody already had that same mistake), and also read a C++ book to get acquainted with the language.

Cheers!

Comment: Oh yeah AndresR - all of the above!  Just have to learn c, c++ now. Instead of giving specs in English Language.  They show a c or c++ routine. Hmmm The way I am calling that as you state is not going to give the desired results.  Oh I see, the caps need to be the same.  ReedSolomon is supposed to fill out the last part of WD array with the error correction codewords (20 of them).  The 50 is supposed to be passed to ReedSolomon as a value not a pointer - do I put *50 then?

Comment: *50 won't work because:
`int *i;` means "The content of address i is an integer". This is a pointer declaration. when you say `*i = 42;` you are saying, roughly, "the content of i is 42". When you say i = 42, you are saying "the address of i is of value 42" which is wrong. if you say int *i; int *j  and then i = j; then you are saying "i and j have the same address". That is what * is used for, it's called "dereferencing" a pointer, which is accessing its value.

Comment: You can also say int k = *b; "k is the content of pointer b", or you can also use it like this: 

`int i;
int *k;

k = &i;`

where k = &i means "the address of k is the address of i". The ampersand (the & symbol) is used in this way to get the address of a variable, so &i means "the address of i". Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks to you great people - hobbs, AndresR, Dan, etc.  I got it compiled properly and it is working!  I fixed my for loop to display the results and the numbers were added on to the end of the array and all looked good!  Now to plug these into my assembler "data matrix barcode create" routine and see if I get a scannable bar code.  Then have to fix my assembler to generate like this c++ routine!!  Thanks 1,000 times over!  Couldn't done it W/O you!!

Answer (score 0):

C++ requires that you cast the return value of `malloc` to whatever type of pointer you're assigning it to. So e.g. `log = malloc(sizeof(int) * gf);` needs to become `log = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * gf);`.

Comment: Cool - you guys are hot on it! I fixed those as hobbs suggested. And that took care of the "void to int" errors. I had all the indents etc but I think it turned to trash when I submitted. I guess heavyd fixed it for me - thank you. All that is left is to run the reedsolomon function.  Compiler seems to think it's an idenitifer that it can't find??  Thanks again, anyone needs help in mainframe assembler - give a shout :)

Answer (score 0):

You should type cast when assigning a pointer to the return of malloc.

Example:

```
log = reinterpret_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int) * gf));
```